# react-navigation: Is it possible to pass a callback to children (e.g.changeHandler)?

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

What I've been trying is to **pass a callback into a screen**.

Here is an excerpt of my experimentation...

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    };

    handleOnPress(data){
    //How do we pass this callback to "Home" or "Sub"?
    }

    render() {
        const Navigator = StackNavigator({
            Home: {screen: Home},
            Sub:  {screen: Sub}
        });
        let data = {blah:"blah blah"};

        return (<Navigator screenProps={data} />);
    }
}
```

In this example, I can get `this.props.screenProps.blah` in both `Home` and `Sub`.
I assumed that being able to pass a prop would mean being able to pass a call back too, but I feel like I wasn't right.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to pass a callback to a child, you could specify in your render as a prop too:

```
<Navigator callback={this.handleOnPress} {/*And any other props you want to pass*/} />
```

And then in your `Home` or `Sub` class to trigger the callback as you probably expect

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    //...
    somefunction = () => {
        this.props.callback();
    }
}
```

This is what I am using in my code right now.

Though if you want to pass it to only either one of `Home` or `Sub`, this here is probably your answer: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/935

```
const mapNavigationStateParamsToProps = (SomeComponent) => {
    return class extends Component {
        static navigationOptions = SomeComponent.navigationOptions; // better use hoist-non-react-statics
        render() {
            const {navigation: {state: {params}}} = this.props
            return <SomeComponent {...params} {...this.props} />
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: In my case, my handler was an arrow function written like so:

```
handleOnPress = (data) => {
    //Do something here
}
```

It is so that I do not have to deal with `.bind()`s

**FINAL SOLUTION by OP**:
Looks like `StackNavigator` requires props to be passed as `screenProps`, so, render function becomes:

```
render() {
    const Navigator = StackNavigator({
        Home: {screen: Home},
        Sub:  {screen: Sub}
    });
    let props = {
        data: "data",
        handleOnPress: () => this.handleOnPress()
    };

    return (<Navigator screenProps={props} />);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, putting `callback={this.function}` into `<Navigator/>` doesn't work for me. Is your app using the latest version, or is that `StackNavigator`? I see an error message, saying `this.props.handleOnPress is not a function`

Comment: When you put `callback={this.function}`, you're passing the prop `callback` containing `this.function`. So if you want to trigger the callback you should call it `this.props.callback()` instead of `this.props.handleOnPress()`. 

Or, just put `handleOnPress={this.handleOnPress}` into `<Navigator/>` so you can call `this.props.handleOnPress()` instead. Try again and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: I honestly have not used `StackNavigator` myself, but my web app does have something like this to handle states across component classes. Also, the reason you're getting the error `this.props.handleOnPress is not a function` is probably because of you passed it as a prop named `callback` and not `handleOnPress`, which means `handleOnPress` is `undefined`.

Comment: Again, thank you for your advice! In my case, however, there was a different solution - `const props = {handleOnPress:() => this.handleOnPress()};
 <Navigator  screenProps={props} />`

Comment: I tried your second approach, but it didn't work, which might be because I'm using `StackNavigator`

Comment: Nice job! Probably is that `StackNavigator` requires props to be passed as `screenProps`. Glad to hear it's working. I'll update my answer with your solution, or suggest an edit instead. Or maybe post it your own! :)

Answer (score 6):

passing a callback through react native navigation params is not recommended, this may cause the state to freeze (to not to update correctly). The better solution here would be using an EventEmitter, so the callback stays in the Screen1 and is called whenever the Screen2 emits an event.

Screen 1 code :

```
import DeviceEventEmitter from "react-native"

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener("event.testEvent", (eventData) => 
callbackYouWantedToPass(eventData)));
```

Screen 2 code:

```
import DeviceEventEmitter from "react-native"

DeviceEventEmitter.emit("event.testEvent", {eventData});

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners("event.mapMarkerSelected")
    };
}, []);
```